# SQL Reset row_number when column value changed

Tags: sql, sql-server-2017

I've been trying to solve this but failed to do so. I need to get the duration of how long does a server has been unavailable. Here is the following data

```
Date  |  Time  |  Address  |  Status
11-14 |  6:32  |  1.1.1.1  |  Down --- Count Start
11-14 |  6:34  |  1.1.1.1  |  Down
11-14 |  6:54  |  1.1.1.1  |  UP
11-14 |  7:20  |  1.1.1.1  |  Down --- Reset Count to 1
11-14 |  7:25  |  1.1.1.1  |  Down
11-14 |  7:30  |  1.1.1.1  |  Up
11-14 |  7:40  |  1.1.1.1  |  Down --- Reset Count to 1
11-14 |  6:35  |  2.2.2.2  |  Down --- Now this is a different counter cause of different IP
```

I have this query

```
SELECT [date]
  ,[time]
  ,[address]
  ,[ms]
  ,[bytes]
  ,[ttl]
  ,[Status]
  ,COALESCE(lag([Status]) over(order by [time]),'--') [Row]
  INTO #temp
FROM
(
SELECT [date]
  ,[time]
  ,[address]
  ,[ms]
  ,[bytes]
  ,[ttl]
  ,CASE WHEN [status] = 'Success' THEN 'UP' ELSE 'DOWN' END [Status]
 FROM [ESPS].[dbo].[Ping History] p
 INNER JOIN [SuperDashboard].[dbo].[IP_Mapping] i ON i.[IP] = p.address
 WHERE [Date] = CONVERT(Date,GETDATE())
) a

SELECT [date]
  ,[time]
  ,[address]
  ,[ms]
  ,[bytes]
  ,[ttl]
  ,[Status]
FROM
(
SELECT [date]
  ,[time]
  ,[address]
  ,[ms]
  ,[bytes]
  ,[ttl]
  ,[Status]
  ,CASE WHEN [Status] != [Row] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [row]
FROM #temp
) a WHERE [row] = 1
DROP TABLE #temp
```

but this is only applicable with only one address as things get mixed up when I try to add `2.2.2.2`. The ideal output of this is to get the duration of downtime of a server everytime it encounters a downtime. I hope someone can help me with this or point me to the right direction atleast.

Edit 1: Expected output should be

```
Date  |  Start DownTime  |  End DownTime  | Address
11-14 |      6:32        |     6:54       | 1.1.1.1
11-14 |      7:20        |     7:30       | 1.1.1.1
11-14 |      7:40        |                | 1.1.1.1
11-14 |      6:35        |                | 2.2.2.2
```

Comment: can you show your expected result based on your above source data?

Comment: @im_one question has been updated sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a type of "group-and-islands" problem.  If you can combine all the downs and following up (if any) into a single group, then the rest is just aggregation.

And, you can do this by counting the number of UPs that occur on or after each record.  This is a simple cumulative sum, and then the rest is aggregation:

```
select address, date, grp,
       min(case when status = 'DOWN' then time end) as startDown,
       max(case when status = 'UP' then time end) as endUp
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when status = 'UP' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by address, date order by time desc) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by address, date, grp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use lag() function

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=361da18b60b1e86ccbbc2d3fc6cd183f)**

```
select *,case when stat='Down' and (prevval='Up' or prevval is null) then 1 else 0 end as val from
(
 select *,lag(stat) over(partition by address order by address) as prevval
 from #temp
)A
```

OUTPUT:

```
address stat    prevval val
1.1.1.1 Down            1
1.1.1.1 Up      Down    0
1.1.1.1 Down    Up      1
1.1.1.1 Down    Down    0
1.1.1.1 Up      Down    0
1.1.1.1 Down    Up      1
1.1.1.1 Down    Down    0
2.2.2.2 Down            1
```

Comment: hi sir I added the final expected output can you check it out?